# Anything similar to Emacs' buffer/window support for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, emacs

I'm trying to make the switch from Emacs to Eclipse.  One thing that seems to be missing is its buffer/window support.

I know in Eclipse I can drag an editor's tab title over to split the view, creating the equivalent of a new Emacs window, which is a step in the right direction.

I can't find any key bindings for this functionality, though.  Ideally, I'd like to be able to set keys to split horizontal, split vertical, switch to next (there is a next editor, but I want the next window/whatever you call it), switch to previous, close this window split (not this editor), close all other editor window splits.

As it is, the only way I've found to close a split pane is to drag all the files over one by one until none are left.  Things like this make working with split screens tedious in Eclipse.

Any help would be appreciated, hopefully there's something simple I'm missing.

Answer (score 3):

Emacs+ has this exact behavior for Eclipse: http://www.mulgasoft.com/emacsplus

Answer (score 1):

According to the [keys preference](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/accessibility/keyboardshortcuts.htm) there is an unbound command to open a new editor, which would open another tab rather than split the view.  There is also an unbound command to close all other editors.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> will close the current editor and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> will switch between tabs.  You can bind or rebind these to be closer to their Emacs equivalents.  Alternatively there is an Emacs key map which you may find more helpful.  Unfortunately I don't it's possible to split the view from the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> for cycling through tabs (buffers) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd> for closing a tab.  You can also look through the shortcut bindings in the eclipse configuration.